# linux sed parsing cut string

Tags: sed

i wont to cut my string with sed but i dont know how it works

my string:

```
../config_export-import/JCRAPI-usecases-export-doc-10.xml
```

I need get only :

```
JCRAPI-usecases-export-doc-10.xml
```

This not static string, "config_export-import" path always different, but always static is 
"JCRAPI-usecases-"

Comment: Showing your sed code would be useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couple of ideas:

```
sed 's/^.*JCRAPI-usecases-/JCRAPI-usecases-/'

grep -o "JCRAPI-usecases-.*"

basename ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's;.*\(/JCRAPI-usecases-\);\1;'
```